# Passing security exception back to client when using role based authorisation in WCF

Tags: wcf-security

I am creating a WCF (with callbacks) service currently hosted as a process but will be a service eventually.
I am using netTCP binding in a Windows Domain environment and the client is on another machine within the domain (windows forms client).
I have all the binding, methods etc working with Windows security at transport level and an SPN in place.

I am now implementing security and am attempting to use this pattern on some methods (not all need to be secured):

```
<PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role="MyDomain\DataReader")>
public Function GetData() As String

    return "Test String"
End Function
```

(example)
This correctly allows users and blocks those not in role.

My problem is that an exception is raised at the service end (I can see this in VS as the process is run from there). The client does not get an security exception but times out instead.

How do I correctly pass back to the caller that a security exception occurred so that the I can then pass a message to the user.